# Detect other class ComboBox change in Form

Tags: c#

I want to detect ComboBox selectedindex change.
The combobox is located in different class then the Form class:

```cs
class Analyze
    {
        public Analyze(Form theform)
        {
            size = new ComboBox();
            size.Location = new Point(100,100);
            size.Name = "matrixsize";
            size.Size= new Size(200,100);
            size.Items.AddRange(matrix_sizes);
            theform.Controls.Add(size);
        }
        private string[] matrix_sizes = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0" };
        private ComboBox size;
    }
```

and im creating a new object of type Analyze right here:

```
private void Analyze_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Analyze analyze = new Analyze(this);
}
```

and now i want to detect the change of values in Analyze.size, how can i do it? what is the right way to access the size combobox?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Add an event to the Analyze class.

Comment: You added the combo box to the form, so it is not "located in a different class", it's attached to the form. You can access it from the form as `theform.Controls["matrixsize"]` because you assigned "matrixsize" to the Name property.

Answer (score 1):

Just add your own handler:

```
class Analyze {
  public event EventHandler SelectedIndexChanged;

  public Analyze(Form theform) {

    ...
    size.SelectedIndexChanged += size_SelectedIndexChanged;
    theform.Controls.Add(size);
  }

  void size_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (SelectedIndexChanged != null) {
      SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e);
    }
  }
}
```

then stub out your event on the calling form:

```
private void Analyze_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  Analyze analyze = new Analyze(this);
  analyze.SelectedIndexChanged += analyze_SelectedIndexChanged;
}

void analyze_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // do something
}
```